# Rails save and create function throwing in an extra method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes, save, instance, strong-parameters

I am able to create a new instance of my Team class successfully, but whenever I call save on the instance I get:

```
undefined method `title' for #<Team:0x00007fddfc7fb570>
```

This is in my "team_attributes=" method, so it is running off of strong params, which does not include a :title method or attribute.

```
def created_user_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :privilege,
            position_attributes: [
                :title,
                :description,
                :team_id,
            ],
            :team_attributes => [
                :name,
                :description,
                :id,
                :profile #for determining if the form came from the profile page. Do not allow into update or create method for team
            ]
        ).with_defaults(user_id: current_user.id)
    end
```

And here is my "team_attributes=" method:

```
def team_attributes=(team_attributes)
        self.update(user_id: self.id) if self.user_id.nil?
        binding.pry
        # selecting a team from a dropbox
        if !team_attributes[:id].nil?
            @team = Team.find_by(id: team_attributes[:id]) 
        # updating an existing team
        elsif self.position && team_attributes[:name]!="" && team_attributes[:profile].nil?
        self.team.update(team_attributes.with_defaults(company: self.company, user_id: self.user_id))
                @team = self.team
        else
        # creating a team from the profile page
            if team_attributes[:profile] == "profile"
                @team = Team.create(name: team_attributes[:name], description: team_attributes[:description], company: self.creator.company, user_id: self.user_id )
        # creating a team
            elsif team_attributes[:name] != ''
                @team = Team.new(team_attributes.except(:profile).with_defaults(company: self.company, user_id: self.user_id))
                @team.save
            else
            end
        end
        self.update(assigned_position_id: @position.id) if self.position

        if @position
        @position.update(team_id: @team.id) if @team 
        end
    end
```

This is where the instance is being created

```
# creating a team from the profile page
            if team_attributes[:profile] == "profile"
                @team = Team.create(name: team_attributes[:name], description: team_attributes[:description], company: self.creator.company, user_id: self.user_id )
```

I am not sure where the error is coming from. You can see from the params and method there is no "title" attribute. Running "new" creates a new instance fine, but saving it through "save" or "create" raises the error above. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did u maybe put some callback / validation called title on team?

Comment: That was exactly what I did. I meant to put :name instead of :title in my validations. Cheers.